# Powershell script to copy folder structure and specific file types

Tags: powershell

I have the following script to copy the folder structure (including empty folders) and specific file types into another directory. However, the issue is that the script copies all files instead of just the `.dat` and `.py` files even though I'm using the `-Include` switch. How to fix this so that it only copies the desired file types

```
$sourceDir = "C:\User\001"
$targetDir = "C:\User\002"
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Include '*.dat', '*.py' -Container
```

Comment: if you can, i recommend you use `robocopy` for this since it is _directory_ oriented instead of _file_ oriented. plus, it is almost always faster & more reliable. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's a valid point. `robocopy $sourceDir $targetDir *.dat *.py /e` Although I think it's useful to explain how the `-Include` switch works.

Comment: Great, `robocopy` works perfectly well! thanks!

Comment: @Chipmunk_da - kool! glad to know that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Lee_Dailey pointed out, it's probably best to use robocopy for this:

```
robocopy $sourceDir $targetDir *.dat *.py /e
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is tricky. You should look up the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1) for the `-Include` parameter

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

You could make it work like this:

```bsh
Copy-Item $sourceDir\* -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Include '*.dat', '*.py'
```

`-Container` is true by default, so you can safely omit it.

Note that you can always use the `-WhatIf` switch to check if you command will actually do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it doesn't do anything for some reason

Comment: I fired `Copy-Item $sourceDir\* -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Include '*.dat', '*.py' -whatif` but that doesn't return anything either

Comment: @Chipmunk_da I suppose it doesn't work with sub-folders. See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it work like this:
i use -Filter

> Specifies a filter to qualify the Path parameter. The FileSystem
> provider is the only installed PowerShell provider that supports the
> use of filters. You can find the syntax for the FileSystem filter
> language in about_Wildcards. Filters are more efficient than other
> parameters, because the provider applies them when the cmdlet gets the
> objects rather than having PowerShell filter the objects after they're
> retrieved.

```
@('*.dat', '*.py') | %{Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir -Destination  $targetDir -Recurse -Filter $_ -Force}
```

or

```
Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir -Destination  $targetDir -Recurse -Filter '*.dat' -Force
Copy-Item -Path $sourceDir -Destination  $targetDir -Recurse -Filter '*.py' -Force
```

it should work but

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
> contents of an item, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character
> specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

```
Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Include '*.dat', '*.py'
```

may find it easier to include files that can be excluded

```
Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Exclude'*.da1', '*.xxx
```